# AWS pricing for S3 object download using site-to-site VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I would like to understand the monthly cost of using a VPN site-to-site link to transport data from S3 to my on-premises host. I will use AWS Lambda to transfer around 12 TB of data each month from S3.

Using AWS calculator, I checked the S3 and VPC tabs and noticed that there is a "Data Transfer OUT" in both services.

For this use-case will I have to pay the "Data tranfer out" fees for each service?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this use-case will I have to pay the "Data tranfer out" fees for each service? Thanks

You can create a [VPC S3 Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) to make the S3 service accessible for your Lambda function without counting outbound data.

> I will use AWS Lambda to transfer around 12 TB of data each month from S3

You will still pay internet outbound from VPC.

If you plan to transfer the data to your on-premise destination, you may consider establish the (already mentioned) [AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) service

Answer (score 1):

**Data Transfer Out** is charged when data goes from AWS to the Internet. It is only charged once, at the exit point.

If data is going across an **AWS Direct Connect** link, then the Data Transfer price is lower.

Comment: So if the data is being transfered from S3 using a Site-to-site VPN it will only charge the Data Out Transfer cost of the VPC service, right?

Comment: Think of Data Transfer as being outside of a specific service, applying as it leaves the AWS boundary. That's why the data transfer charge is the same for every service, because it is "outside" of any particular service.